# not scrape image in Goutte library in php

Tags: php

i trying below code but result is blank.
someone can help to how i scrape image.

```
$client = new Client(HttpClient::create(['timeout' => 60]));

$url = 'https://www.gumtree.com.au/s-wheels-tyres-rims/tyres/k0c18476';

$selector = 'div.user-ad-collection-new-design__wrapper--row > a';

$req = $client->request('GET', $url);


$req->filter($selector)->each(function (Crawler $node) {
     $node->html(); 
                       
    $description = $node->filter('div p.user-ad-row-new-design__description-text')->text();
    $price = $node->filter('div span.user-ad-price-new-design__price')->text();
    $location = $node->filter('div.user-ad-row-new-design__location')->text();
    $title = $node->filter('p span.user-ad-row-new-design__title-span')->text();
    $time = $node->filter('p.user-ad-row-new-design__age')->text();           
    $link = 'https://www.gumtree.com.au'.$node->attr('href');       

 $node->filter('img')->each(function ($node) {
       echo $node->attr('src').'<br>';
    }
```

Comment: Error message s??

Comment: What is `Client` can we see that class definition

Comment: not an error but page is blank

Comment: I am guessing you are using a framework too? Or at least some external libraries??

Comment: i am using laravel framework